# How to fix "The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken." in Azure DevOps Pipelines?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, azure-pipelines, fastlane

I'm getting this error when uploading to the Apple App Center via Azure DevOps Pipelines (which uses Fastlane):

ERROR ITMS-90129: "The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken."

Question: How do I fix this?

Google seems to indicate that this error message is common, but I haven't seen anyone who sees this error in Azure DevOps Pipelines.

Background:
The app has been around for years. We have been uploading via XCode the entire time. In fact, uploading via XCode still works without an error. This would seem to indicate that it's a Pipelines or Fastlane problem, not an Apple problem. (That is, Apple doesn't complain about the bundle name of display name if uploading to the App Store using XCode.)

What changed:
We are trying to implement a CI/CD pipeline on Azure DevOps, using the "Publish to the App Store TestFlight Track" step. The bundle ID in the pipeline step matches the bundle ID that's in the info.plist and that matches what's in the Apple App Store. We have added a couple new features since the last upload to the App Store, but have not changed the bundle id, bundle name, or display name.

Looking at the log from Azure DevOps Pipelines, it looks like Fastlane is correctly finding the existing application. The log shows that it's uploading to the correct Apple App Id. One would think that it would allow the app to be uploaded, using the existing bundle name and display name. If either are in use, it's our App Id that's using them.

Here's the log of the pipeline step from DevOps: (Some sensitive values have been changed for privacy.)

```
##[section]Starting: Publish to the App Store TestFlight track
==============================================================================
Task         : Apple App Store Release
Description  : Release an app to TestFlight or the Apple App Store
Version      : 1.158.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.app-store)
==============================================================================
bee538a5-46c9-4cd2-9fca-b847cc5a5080 exists true
[command]/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/gem install fastlane
Successfully installed rubyzip-1.3.0
Successfully installed fastlane-2.133.0
Parsing documentation for rubyzip-1.3.0
Installing ri documentation for rubyzip-1.3.0
Parsing documentation for fastlane-2.133.0
Installing ri documentation for fastlane-2.133.0
Done installing documentation for rubyzip, fastlane after 21 seconds
2 gems installed
[command]/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/gem update fastlane -i /Users/vsts/.gem-cache
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
[command]fastlane pilot upload -u *** -i /Users/vsts/agent/2.158.0/work/1/s/my.ipa -q 117232819 -r Company, Inc. opt_out_usage
[13:58:55]: ‌Get started using a Gemfile for fastlane https:&#x2F;&#x2F;docs.fastlane.tools&#x2F;getting-started&#x2F;ios&#x2F;setup&#x2F;#use-a-gemfile‌
[13:58:56]: Sending anonymous analytics information
[13:58:56]: Learn more at https://docs.fastlane.tools/#metrics
[13:58:56]: No personal or sensitive data is sent.
[13:58:56]: You can disable this by adding `opt_out_usage` at the top of your Fastfile
[13:58:56]: Login to App Store Connect (***)
Session loaded from environment variable is not valid. Continuing with normal login.
[13:58:58]: Login successful
[13:59:00]: Ready to upload new build to TestFlight (App: 953681025)...
[13:59:00]: Fetching password for transporter from environment variable named `FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD`
[13:59:18]: iTunes Transporter successfully finished its job
[13:59:18]: Fetching password for transporter from environment variable named `FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD`
[13:59:18]: Going to upload updated app to App Store Connect
[13:59:18]: This might take a few minutes. Please don't interrupt the script.
[13:59:39]: [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90129: "The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken."
[13:59:39]: Transporter transfer failed.
[13:59:39]: 
[13:59:39]: ERROR ITMS-90129: "The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken."
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this? I'm having a similar problem. Thanks.

Comment: I did not. We gave up on it about a month after the original post.

Comment: I have the same problem in 2022, after 100+ uploads to TestFlight it just stopped working. Renaming the bundle and changing the bundle id doesn't help. I'm also using Fastlane.

Comment: @Nik could you solve this problem?

Comment: @FlavioH.Freitas I wasn't able to upload the app with my original name anymore. I renamed everything (appstore name, build product, display name) multiple times and it worked for me eventually.

Comment: Tks @Nik. We will keep trying then, and I will inform you if we find out something.

Comment: We could solve this problem by:

- We are using the newest version of Xcode
- Changed the bundle name where it was being referenced
- Added a fix in Cocoapods to ignore code-signing on 'bundles'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your bundle identifier most likely, try changing it slightly then re-uploading.

Comment: get to the general settings page of your project and then update the Bundle identifier to a new unique name, its just a text box under the general tab

Comment: Great! Now I just need you to hit that edit button on your answer and give a more detailed explanation, perhaps with pictures. I'm actually not having this problem; I'm just here to make sure others are getting the best answer.